# Summarize by group to make a composite key

Tags: sql, postgresql, sas, proc-sql

I've a detailed table like:

```
COMPANY  DATE  GROUP AMT
Sentana  12Dec  A    1200
Sentana  12Dec  B     800
Toyq     12Dec  A    1300
Toyq     12Dec  A     100
Sentana  12Dec  B     300
Toyq     13Dec  A     700
Sentana  12Dec  A     800
```

Now I wants to make a composite unique key based on the 3 columns(COMPANY  DATE  GROUP), so to have an output like:

```
COMPANY  DATE  GROUP AMT
Sentana  12Dec  A    2000
Sentana  12Dec  B    1100
Toyq     12Dec  A    1400
Toyq     13Dec  A     700
```

I've used query(SQL) like:
    Create table TEMP as
    select DISTINCT COMPANY,  DATE,  GROUP, sum(AMT) from table
    group by COMPANY,  DATE,  GROUP

```
Error: The AMT gets increased to many folds maybe 
because there are some more columns.
```

Note: I need to create a table with a composite key based on the 3 columns(COMPANY  DATE  GROUP) so that I can join it with the other table.I can create composite key by concatenating the three but due to repeated combinations of the 3 columns, it become difficult to get the desired result.

Comment: Which RDBMS You're using?

Comment: avoid `Distinct` from your select clause

Comment: I'm using SAS which uses PostgreSQL as backend, I guess. It also supports SQL syntax by using PROC SQL command.

Comment: Except for the fact that `group` is a reserved word, your query looks fine.  The `distinct` is unnecessary and should be removed, but it should not be causing an error.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to write a SELECT query or actually add a composite unique key to the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try without `distinct`

```
select COMPANY, DATE, GROUP, sum(AMT) from table group by COMPANY, DATE, GROUP
```

Comment: In that case the composite key doesn't form which is the main objective.

Comment: What do you mean the composite key doesn't get formed? There should only be unique values of the three variables in the group by clause.

Comment: Even if you add an explicit key, the query stays the same. You can add a composite key with: `alter table xx add key(company,date,group)`